# Reading version from vmlinuz using file command

Tags: bash, kernel, version

As the title says:

How to read vmlinuz version (directly) using `file` command?

Using: `file /vmlinuz | grep version`,
It must show like this `4.11.0-9.1-liquorix-amd64`.

Comment: The question specifically asks for the `file` command - however if you stumbled on this question because you just want to read version info from the `vmlinuz` file, not necessarily using the `file` command, then a useful C code sample is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179559/795690

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Initial note

My `file -bL /vmlinuz` returns:

```
Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 3., RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x2, Normal VGA
```

This knowledge may be useful if you need to adjust or debug what follows.

---

#### With `grep`

You used `grep`, that's why at first I assume you want it to be a crucial part of the solution.

`file` generates one line per its argument, `grep` works with entire lines so it *seems* like it's not a right tool here. There is, however, `-o` option which makes `grep` report only matched part of a line. This is non-POSIX in the first place so I don't really care about other parts of the following command being POSIX compliant.

The command is:

```
file -bL /vmlinuz | grep -o 'version [^ ]*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

About `file` options: `-L` makes it follow symbolic links (`/vmlinuz` is often a symlink to `/boot/vmlinuz-something`), `-b` prevents it from printing the filename (because we don't need it anyway).

The interpretation of `version [^ ]*` is: literal `version`, then a literal space, then as many non-space characters as it can get. In your case the output will be `version 4.11.0-9.1-liquorix-amd64`.

Finally `cut` leaves only the second field, having a space as field delimiter. This should produce the output you need.

---

#### Without `grep`

The solution in quite simple form may be:

```
file -bL /vmlinuz | sed 's/.*version //;s/ .*//'
```

It replaces the parts you don't want with empty strings. If the `file` output has unexpected format (e.g. you didn't use `-L` while you should have), the output is non-empty yet invalid. Note the first solution (with `grep`) yields nothing in this case.

With some `sed` tricks we can patch this:

```
file -bL /vmlinuz | sed -n '/version /!q;s/.*version //;s/ .*//p'
```

In the above command `sed` silently quits when there's no `version` in its input. Now, if your `sed` supports this, you may want it to return exit status like this:

```
file -bL /vmlinuz | sed -n '/version /!q1;s/.*version //;s/ .*//p'
```

I consider this last command the best so far.